# Error when using .Contains to check if a string contains a character

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to find out if a string contains a character. I tried the following
where ViewBag.Options is a string:

```
@ViewBag.Options.Contains('q')
```

but it gives me an error saying:

The best overloaded method match for 'string.Contains(string)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: Out of interest, what did you try when you got that error message? Did you understand the error? Did you look at what `string.Contains` *can* take?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

And it's write: [`string.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa) doesn't have an overload taking just a single character.

Options:

- Use `@ViewBag.Options.Contains("q")`
- Use `@ViewBag.Options.IndexOf('q') != -1`
- Use some more complicated LINQy approach (e.g. `Any`) - feasible, but there's no need here. (I'm a fan of LINQ *where appropriate* but I don't think that's the right approach here; I wouldn't start introducing lambda expressions into my code just for the sake of it)
- Use some more complicated regular expression approach - again, there's no point.

Comment: Why complicated when he can do `@ViewBag.Options.Any(x => x == 'q');`?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: Because that's more complicated that `Contains("q")`? I'm far from anti-LINQ, but why use an approach using a lambda expression when a really simple method call will work just as well?

Answer (score 1):

Use any of them

- `@ViewBag.Options.Contains("q");`
- `@ViewBag.Options.Any(x => x == 'q');`

If you insist

- `@ViewBag.Options.Contains('q'.ToString());`

The error is self explanatory. Paramerters of `.Contains` takes a string and no overload of this method takes a character.

Answer (score 1):

Using single quotes in c# indicates a character.

Try with double quotes:

```
@ViewBag.Options.Contains("q");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
@ViewBag.Options.Contains("q")
```